# При создании box с Ubuntu 18.04 с помощью Packer возникает ошибка

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

Задача такая,создать базовый бокс с Ubuntu 18.04 с помощью Packer, выходной формат Vagrant;
основная ось windows 10, поставил на virtualbox Ubuntu 20.04, поставил на неё последнии версии Packer'a, Vagrant'a, virtualbox'a, создал файл конфигурации для packer (все с копипастил с этой репы: https://github.com/serainville/packer_template/tree/c64b612ec5b500a2da2fe894416ab1de9ccc9265/Ubuntu-18.04),
https://github.com/serainville/packer_templates.git
прописал:

`packer build ubuntu-18.04-vagrant.json`

И тут появилась проблема

```
==> virtualbox-iso: Cannot find "Default Guest Additions ISO" in vboxmanage output (or it is empty)
==> virtualbox-iso: Retrieving Guest additions checksums
1 items:  2.91 KiB / 2.91 KiB [============================================] 0s
    virtualbox-iso: Transferred: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.16/SHA256SUMS
==> virtualbox-iso: Retrieving Guest additions
    virtualbox-iso: Found already downloaded, initial checksum matched, no download needed: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.16/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.16.iso
==> virtualbox-iso: Retrieving ISO
    virtualbox-iso: Error downloading: open /home/home/Packer/iso/ubuntu-18.04-server-amd64.iso: no such file or directory
    virtualbox-iso: Error downloading: Error making HTTP GET request: 404 Not Found
==> virtualbox-iso: ISO download failed.
Build 'virtualbox-iso' errored: ISO download failed.

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> virtualbox-iso: ISO download failed.

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

Новая ошибка, которая появилась после запуска с более нового комита:

```
virtualbox-iso: Transferred: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64.iso
==> virtualbox-iso: Starting HTTP server on port 8137
==> virtualbox-iso: Creating virtual machine...
==> virtualbox-iso: Creating hard drive...
==> virtualbox-iso: Creating forwarded port mapping for communicator (SSH, WinRM, etc) (host port 3479)
==> virtualbox-iso: Executing custom VBoxManage commands...
    virtualbox-iso: Executing: modifyvm packer-ubuntu-18.04.1-amd64 --memory 1024
    virtualbox-iso: Executing: modifyvm packer-ubuntu-18.04.1-amd64 --cpus 1
==> virtualbox-iso: Starting the virtual machine...
==> virtualbox-iso: Error starting VM: VBoxManage error: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
==> virtualbox-iso: VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
==> virtualbox-iso: Deregistering and deleting VM...
==> virtualbox-iso: Deleting output directory...
Build 'virtualbox-iso' errored: Error starting VM: VBoxManage error: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> virtualbox-iso: Error starting VM: VBoxManage error: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

В данной теме слишком неопытный, может кто-то из более знающих сможет объяснить причину и направить на более верный путь. Буду благодарен за любуб помочь.

Comment: `с копипастил с этой репы` — а зачем вы взяли содержимое коммита трёхлетней давности, если имеется более новое содержимое, с исправлением ссылок на актуальные? берите из того коммита, на который указывает указатель master.

Comment: запускал и его, ошибка та же

Comment: "404 not found"? для вот этой [ссылки](https://github.com/serainville/packer_templates/blob/master/Ubuntu-18.04/ubuntu-18.04-vagrant.json#L37)?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin поменял на эту:
https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-18.04.5-live-server-amd64.iso
Ошибка та же

Comment: `virtualbox-iso: Error downloading: Error making HTTP GET request: 404 Not Found` в том же самом месте? вообще-то надо было не «менять в одном месте», а взять исходники по указателю master. // если ошибка в том же самом месте, проверьте, во что у вас резолвится имя сервера, с которого скачивается этот iso.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, взял содержимое более нового комита, теперь выбивает другую ошибку

Comment: [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=VT-x+is+not+available)